# C# to Delphi Translation/ Converter

Tags: c#, delphi

Is there are websites that I can translate the code below to Delphi. :

```
       var newpin = new IntPtr();


       newpin = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(8); // what is this function?
       retcode = Namespace.CashierCardInstallation("1234", ref newpin); // static method
       if (retcode != 0)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("installation failed");

       }



       var pin = new byte[8];
       Marshal.Copy(newpin, pin, 0, 8); // what is this function?
```

Or what is the delphi equivalent of those methods with comments? Thank you!

Comment: "Marshal.Copy(newpin, pin, 0, 8); // what is this function?" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146635.aspx - Copies data from an unmanaged memory pointer to a managed 32-bit signed integer array.

Comment: "  newpin = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(8); // what is this function?" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s69bkh17.aspx - Allocates memory from the unmanaged memory of the process by using the specified number of bytes.

Comment: What was your effort on this chunk of code?

Comment: Translating that code won't help you one little bit. What is `Namespace.CashierCardInstallation`?

Answer (score 3):

It's just using `AllocHGlobal` to allocate unmanaged memory, and `Marshal` to do pure memory copies. In Delphi you don't need any of that because you already have native memory at your fingertips.

```
var
  retcode: Integer;
  Pin: array [0..7] of Byte;//or whatever the underlying data type is
begin
  retcode := Namespace.CashierCardInstallation('1234', @Pin);
  if retcode <> 0 then
  begin
    ShowMessage("installation failed");
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @David Ahh yes, forgot you could do that :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Nah it's fine haven't done any Delphi proper in many years.